# How to change the default dowload in selenium webdriver while runningin java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Hello Im having a problem changing the download locations for each different file. It seems that when you the chromedriver is running you cant change the default dl location.Is there any way to change the dl.locaton while chromedriver is running?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.
 [How to change chrome download directory in selenium-webdriver using java](http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2018/08/25/how-to-change-default-download-directory-for-chrome-browser-in-selenium-webdriver/)

Comment: i want to download different file in different folder . example file1 into location 1 the. file2 into location2 . i want to do it without closing the chromedriver current session

Comment: In an instance of Chrome driver you can only change the download location once. If you want to change the download location for each download then you need to quit the driver and open again with new download location in chromeoptions.